# Clean install ASUS ZenPad S 8.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, installation

How to install a clean version of Android (Marshmallow) on my ASUS ZenPad S 8.0. 
I'm sick of all the bloatware.

Comment: There's not even a method for bootloader unlocking (ASUS decided to not provide an official one since they do Zen devices). Even root doesn't seem to be available for MM. Best you can get... [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/rom-debloated-asus-zenpad-s-8-0-64gb-t3445651)